# Playing a mpeg dash stream without initialization segment

Tags: video-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am trying to generate a dash stream playable in dash player. I have a one mp4 video which I have chunked into multiple videos of approximately 10 secs each. Now I would like to play this videos in a dash player where each segment is self initializing.
How could I possibly achieve this without creating a initialization segment.

Comment: How did you 'chunk' them?

Comment: If your segments are playable by themselves then they are **not** segments but just small mp4 files. There is a specific format that DASH videos and the segments must follow.

If you can provide information about what tooling you are using to create these videos, I might be able to give an answer regarding how to properly generate a DASH video with these tools.

Comment: You are right, what I have is small mp4 files. I converted these files into dash segments using bento4. Now the problem I have is generating a single intialization file for all the files combined. Combining all these files to single file and then generating dash stream is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec, it is possible.
This is a quote from the MPEG-DASH ISO/IEC 23009 spec:

> A Representation consists of one or more Segments.
>   Each Representation either shall contain an Initialization Segment or
>   each Media Segment in the Representation shall be self-initializing,
>   i.e. the Media Segment itself conforms to the media type as specified
>   in the @mimeType attribute for this Representation.
>
> When a Representation is not a dependent Representation, i.e. the
>   @dependencyId attribute is absent, then concatenation of the
>   Initialization Segment, if present, and all consecutive Media Segments
>   in one Representation shall represent a conforming Segment sequence as
>   defined in 4.5.3 conforming to the media type as specified in the
>   @mimeType attribute for this Representation

In addition, Initialization element is not mandatory (0...1).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. An initialization segment contains information required to initialize the decoders. For example NalLengthSize in the case of AVC codec, or Audio Specific Config for AAC.

Comment: Is there not any concept of self initializing segment? All my segments are playable by itself.

Comment: How did you create the segments?

Comment: I created small mp4 files using ffmpeg. These files together form one video. I wanted to play these small files like dash streams without initialization segment.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. an mp4 segment is made of an moov and an mdat. a dash segment(usually m4s) is a moof, sidx and an mdat. They are different formats. You can not use one as the other.

Comment: Thanks szatmary. Now I have manged to create proper dash fragments using bento4 for each segment. I could like to create a single initialization segment for all fragments combined. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @YoganandAnandaraju, yeah you could create a single initialization file for all of your segments, but make sure that the codec information in that segment initialization files is exactly the same as the codec info of your fragments. Like the SPS and PPS in the initialization must be the same as your fragments codec params